# Search for a query

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to look through existing queries to see if any of them call on a specific table. 
I am very sure that I can do it by exporting the db and then searching through the sql create statements. But does anyone know how to do this with a sql statement?

Comment: Queries aren't stored in the database. What do you expect to find? Are you looking for the contents of views and stored procedures?

Comment: Interesting Craig. I am looking for the contents of views and stored procedures.  How are they stored?

Comment: @HenryMaher for example you want to get `view name` and `view definition` ?

Comment: Try this : - http://hastebin.com/ireseliwas.sql

Comment: Winged panther that's unbelievable. That's exactly what I was looking for. Your a star.

Comment: That's for views. For stored procs, use `pg_proc.prosrc`.